# Clearing blank entries in database using WHERE

Tags: mysql

**When trying the following command below, my database still shows null values. Could anyone please assist?**

```
Update AmazingAmazonians.Product set URL= "http://www.google.com" where URL='';
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a world of difference between an empty string and actual `NULL` values. You may need:

```
WHERE URL IS NULL
```

Remember, `NULL` is not comparable with `=` or `!=`, you need to use the `IS` or `IS NOT` operators.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the response and advise!, solved it